# auto increment lower-latin letters to html paragraphs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a webpage app that allows a user to use clickboxes that in turn add text to an iFrame.
The text is in forms of topics and subtopics where the user can choose the subtopics that are applicable which are in turn number in sequence as they are added.
I've already gotten or made the code for the topics "1." and some subtopics types "1.1, 1.2 etc", bullets and "1)", but can't quite figure out how to get lower-latin letters e.g. 
a) blahblah, 
b) blahblah
code i have so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $('.Q').each(function(index, element){
                i++;
                $(element).text(i + ') ' + $(element).text());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <a class="Q">test1</a><br>
    <a class="Q">test2</a>

    <br><button>Click me</button> 
</body>
```

Index Lists are out because it needs to adapt, I've thought about an IF type statement but not sure how to make it work along the lines of 'if Q = a, then next Q = b etc'

Is it a case that you can make the letter = a number such as a = 1, b = 2? in which case I haven't a clue yet how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying purpose only, you don't need any js/jq, just use [CSS counter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('.Q').addClass('counter');
});
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: countAlpha;
}
.Q {
  margin-left: 1em;
  counter-increment: countAlpha;
}
.Q.counter::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(countAlpha, lower-alpha) ")";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="Q">test1</a>
<br>
<a class="Q">test2</a>

<br>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For character,
instead of i++ 
Use: `i = String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt(0) + 1)`